# Opengl 2.0 Matrix.rotateM xAngle yAngle

Tags: opengl

I draw cube and want to rotate it using finger movement under the screen. I use this code
`Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, yAngle, 0, 1, 0);
   Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, xAngle, 1, 0, 0);`

and I expect the yAngle  will rotate cube on y axis of the screen and it's ok

and  the xAngle will rotate cube on x axis of the screen, **BUT** it rotated  in the **coordinate system of the cube** not of the coordinate system of screen.

I can't post images because i have only 1 reputation point :( so I upload images and the links :
NOW 
[Rotation as it is now](http://postimg.org/image/o35qqd7t3/)

And I want

[rotation as I want](http://s29.postimg.org/joh4f5tmb/img_good.jpg)

Comment: btw the two images are the same

Comment: I also assume by screen space you actually mean world space.

Comment: does the user rotate the object in an arbitrary order, for example x then y then x then x then y or any other order? if that's so you need to keep the matrix reference from the last frame, which means you need to implement what I said in gamedev. And btw if you want to make euler angles extrinsic make sure you post multiply the matrix with the vector.

Comment: -1, `stack.imgur.com` is there for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [Intrinsic Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Intrinsic_rotations), which by default rotate the points around local axis.  In order to rotate around the global axis you just need to convert them to [extrinsic angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Extrinsic_rotations). which is as simple as [reversing the order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conversion_between_intrinsic_and_extrinsic_rotations) so it becomes:

```
Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, xAngle, 1, 0, 0); 
Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, yAngle, 0, 1, 0);
```

You also need to make sure that you post-multiply row vectors, instead of pre-multiplying ccolumn vectors.

Comment: I understand you, but I need to rotate both axis as Extrinsic rotations. And if I change order?then x -Extrinsic y Intrinsic. I need  x -Extrinsic and y -Extrinsic.

Comment: @rurik if you need a better approach, you can refer to my detailed answer http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-world-aligned-axes/67282#67282

Comment: @rurik but actully when you reverse the both angles become extrinsic

Comment: I understand your explanation, but I don't understand how to add two angle(x and y) into one result angle and result axis. Can you explain me how to do it with matrixes

Comment: @rurik I still think my current answer here is enough for your case.

Comment: @rurik never the less, in order to do what I explained in that answer you need to use quaternions or axis angles representation.

Comment: Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, xAngle, 1, 0, 0); 
Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, yAngle, 0, 1, 0); don't give me what I want. just x angle what I want but Y is not what I want

Comment: @rurik eventhough you didn't show what you exactly want. at this point I assume that you need to implement my other answer which needs quaternions or axis angles.

Comment: If I right understand you,I need to do the following: from xAngle(axis {1,0,0} angle = a ) and yAngle(axis {0,1,0} angle = b ) I need to make result axis {x,y,z} and result angle value c and then do in the code  Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, c, x, y, z); ?

Comment: @rurik I am not sure I follow, but what you need to do is done in this http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67199/how-to-rotate-an-object-around-world-aligned-axes/67269#67269 answer to the same question. Sure without the translation and the scaling part.